# Failed to send key event : Event details : Type 3 Keycode 13 ; unmodified text: , modified text: , modifiers: 0

Tags: selenium, cucumber, webdriver, capybara

I work on a framework developed on cucumber capybara and selenium webdriver. In one of my step definition i use curl command to get a code and in the next step definition i have to enter password.The step definition with curl command is fetching the code but the next step definition is failing because it was not able to enter the password giving the following error

"Failed to send key event : Event details : Type 3 Keycode 13 ; unmodified text: , modified text: , modifiers: 0 "

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keycode 13 is the `Enter` key. You may need to `strip` the results of your `curl` command of whitespace before submitting it as the password.